# What to say if you understood someone after he or she gave more explanations?

Tags: phrase-requests

Yesterday one of my clients asked me a question and I replied to his email but today he again repeated his request and I understood that yesterday I've got it wrong.

Therefore I now need to assure him that I was able to understand him after that he provided more explanation about his problem. How can I say that I was confused yesterday but I got it today?

For example something like this:

Hmm, Now I grasp what you said ... (but very formal)

Comment: "After some reflection, I realize that I originally misinterpreted your question when you asked it yesterday. Thanks to the additional information you sent today, however, I now understand the precise nature of your question. ..."

Comment: Or, ***Now** I get it!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apologize first because you were confused yesterday. Then you could try to tell him that you now understand what the problem is. Maybe, a few clarifications would make him believe that you now understand it already.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I humbly apologize for the misunderstanding regarding this matter yesterday. As of today, upon providing additional explanations regarding the problem, I believe that I have now a deeper understanding of the actual problem that we are facing. I would like to clarify (then state your understanding of the problem).

Comment: This is potentially confusing if the client isn't already aware that OP misunderstood something, as beginning with that implies that OP thinks the client knows there's something to apologise for. There's also a dangling modifier with "As of today, upon providing additional explanations regarding the problem, I believe..." as this makes it sound like it was OP who provided additional explanations, which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: Base on the situation that he stated, the client knew that he has not fully understand the problem yet. If I were the client, and I think you have understand it yesterday, I wouldn't be needing to explain it further to you today? Kindly correct me  if my idea was wrong. Thanks